# No default font in Windows 10 1803

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, fonts

The following single line of code in a WinForm application (.NET 4.5) on Windows 10 1803 returns a different object from previous Windows 10 updates:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Font f = new Font("", 2048, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

From Win10 1803:

> {Name = "" Size=2048}

Earlier:

> {Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif" Size=2048}

Is there any technical reason for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not actually supply it:  SystemFonts.DefaultFont?

Comment: According to [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdte89fc(v=vs.110).aspx): "_For localized applications that are based on the .NET Framework 2.0 and earlier releases, specifying a font for prototype when that font has not been installed on the computer that is used to build your application will cause the Microsoft Sans Serif font to be used instead. If your application depends on this behavior and you must recompile your application for the .NET Framework 3.0, you should specify the Microsoft Sans Serif font for prototype._", which suggests it's been planned for a long time.